# How to convert this SQL statement to laravel code?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I have two tables Animals and Adoptions

The animal table holds [animalID, name, DOB]

Adoptions hold [id, animalID, userID, approved]

I need to write a statement which would match the animalID in both the tables and would return the name and DOB of the animal where approved is 0.

I have hardly any previous experience with either mySQL or Laravel so my assumption would be that the SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT animalName, DOB
FROM animal
INNER JOIN
Adoption ON adoption.animalID = animal.animalID
WHERE 
Adoption.approved = 0
```

Currently I am returning all of the animals in the table. So I need to add the join and do the checking to see if the animalID in the adoptions table has a value of 0

```
public function available  ()
{
    //JOIN ANIMAL AND ADOPTION TABLES
    //RETURN ALL ANIMALS WHERE APPROVED = 0


    $animalQuery = Animal::all();



    return view('/available', array('animals'=>$animalQuery));
}
```

Comment: Are you using eloquent models?

Comment: yes @thisiskelvin

Answer (score 1):

```
public function available  ()
{
    //JOIN ANIMAL AND ADOPTION TABLES
    //RETURN ALL ANIMALS WHERE APPROVED = 0


    $animalQuery = Animal::select('animals.id','animals.name', 'animals.DOB')
        ->join('adoptions', 'adoptions.animalid', '=', 'animals.id')
        ->where('adoptions.approved', 0)
        ->get();



    return view('/available', array('animals'=>$animalQuery));
}
```

This is my answer which worked for me

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you would need two models. An Animal model and an Adoption model. Laravel uses models to access your database table.

Using the Animal model you could create a query like this:

```
\App\Animal::with('adoption')->select('name','dob')->get();
```

Then inside your Animal model, you would need to create the relationship between the animal and adoption:

```
public function adoption()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Animal', 'animalID', 'animalID');
}
```

This would be one way to get an animal, with the adoption information.

I really recommend reading through the Laravel documentation for relationships and eloquent, and possibly read up on some SQL.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `Adoption` model, and `adoption` relation on your `Animal` model, you can do the following:

```
$animals = Animal::select('animalName`, `DOB`)
    ->with(['adoption' => function($query) {
        $query->where('approved', false);
    })->get();
```